# DKIM fails for potion of the emails sent from server, according to DMARC report, what could be the cause?

Tags: dkim, dmarc

I see in the report from Google that from the server IP address a potion of email failed.
**What could be the reason for that?** (That DKIM passes for some emails, while it fails for others.)

Report shapshot:

```
 <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>209.126.119.66</source_ip>
      <count>40</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>numbeo.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <spf>
        <domain>numbeo.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>

...

 <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>209.126.119.66</source_ip>
      <count>70</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>numbeo.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>numbeo.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>mail</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>numbeo.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

So for the 40 emails sent from 209.126.119.66 DKIM failed, while for 70 passed.

My DKIM configuration is specified here:

https://mladenadamovic.wordpress.com/2018/01/17/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-lts/

Comment: Did you configure your DKIM a few days back when you received those reports?

Comment: I did implement a DMARC record, the previous one was invalid. But also the following day (when DNS should already be propagated) I got errors from gmail.

Comment: Did you recheck the reports again now. Maybe at that time reports were mixed because change was made recently.

Comment: ok, I have opened the last report from the Google and the problem still persist, 79 emails passed DKIM, 18 emails dkim fail while spf passed